# Shortcut for NodeJS server

Tags: software-engineering, node.js

I am tired of typing  "cd c:\socket\nodejs"
                      "node testserver.js"

Into the command promt..

How do I create a shortcut or bat for it?

Comment: you create .bat file and write these two lines into it :)

Comment: @Kikaimaru Exactly. You should post this as an answer!

Comment: @Laurent Couvidou: I think there are better ways, like automatic restart when you change .js files or running it from webstorm and seeing output in IDE, maybe someone will write some of them in more verbose answer :)

Comment: @Kikaimaru Thank you for the idea of an automatic restart when changed. I will look that up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly as you asked, create a `.bat` file and inside type:

```
cd c:\socket\nodejs
node testserver.js
```

But what I would suggest is installing this thing I came across the other day called [Lineman](https://github.com/testdouble/lineman). It makes use of [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to automatically check for file updates on the fly. It also has built in support for [Test'Em](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) which makes unit testing a breeze. Using all of this, you could write a batch script more like this:

```
cd c:\socket\nodejs
lineman run
```

then just go from there without even needing to run `node` periodically. Furthermore, you could create a second batch like so:

```
cd c:\socket\nodejs
lineman spec
```

and keep that open so you can check in and make sure all of your unit tests are always passing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I will look the Lineman up, but probably go with your first answer on how to create a Bat File because I like to check the Client-Side while the server is running, and the Lineman sounds more like a debugger.

Comment: No problem :) And Lineman can be used as a debugger of sorts but it's really intended for client and server side stuff. Any time you modify any of your js files it essentially "restarts." So you wouldn't need to shut down `testserver.js` and reboot it every time you modify it. Same goes for any of your other scripts that are run through `testserver.js`. Glad I could help.